# How to Fold (FoldList) this in a more compact (efficient) way?

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, code-review, pure-function

Example code:

```
x = Table[something[i], {i, 5}]
Table[Fold[f1[#1, f2[#2, a], a] &, x[[i]], {c1, c2, c3}], {i, Length[x]}]
```

This above is just an example. I wonder is there a more compact way to achieve the same thing?

Full example :

```
kappa = Uncompress["1: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"];

ss = Uncompress["1:eJztV10LgjAUNbeyj1/RP4g0gh6rxx6ieuzJUBgYiUv6+TWpTOnO3WmRgT6MXe52djw7B3Honjb+wDAMTsWwYvzsm89qEwfeveqJYRu7/BCx8MxbogpZ0pB1OWulXTUSKUQyNZBoIRLRQGoXIlEUUkdU+9nIXjjcekyXk7EctV0e1ZajdsqjOnJU6x2VPqt1EPN7L3mjHTt6XAZ0yRgFJjRfpNPlBI2aN82LkOSMqeqCqrEh5dmAF4tik7uOjMzpCnYVD+ZisDtM7R0VhAG9WSAMZOLu502cLF6fLl6EpgfJhtU4c9IXfa7HkHyMId77IMP/CkBVsfB5UHy5e7UIRV6YOoZCi+FPQgExbEKhFAsKRb8WoaBG3UOhxfAnoYAYNqFQigWFIvltvAG3yPPe"]


pars = Variables[kappa];

Table[
    Fold[PolynomialReduce[#1, GroebnerBasis[#2, pars], pars][[2]] &, kappa[[i]], Reverse[Subtract @@@ ss]]
    , {i, Length[kappa]}
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Takes about 7.8 seconds on my laptop.

`kappa` is a complicated term where can be simplified using rules `ss`. Each of the terms in `kappa` is done using each of the terms in the rule one by one.

Thanks!

Comment: This is no faster but is a little cleaner: `x = Array[something, 5]; Table[Fold[f1[#1, f2[#2, a], a] &, i, {c1, c2, c3}], {i, x}]`

Comment: ~9% gain on not calculating `GB` each time: `GroebnerBasis[#, pars] & /@ Reverse[Subtract @@@ ss]; Table[
 Fold[PolynomialReduce[#, #2, pars][[2]] &, i, gb],
 {i, kappa}]`